# How to pass command line arguments to a Windows app from within the Git Bash?

Tags: windows, shell, command-line, git-bash

I'm trying to run `devenv` from within the Git Bash on Windows. `devenv` takes arguments such as `/build Debug` or `/projectconfig Debug`. Writing

```
devenv MySolution.sln /build Debug /project MyProj/MyProj.csproj
```

fails, and `devenv` thinks `/build` is a file in the current folder.

On the other hand,

```
devenv MySolution.sln --build=Debug --project=MyProj/MyProj.csproj
```

also fails.

How to pass the arguments properly from within the Git Bash?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm pretty sure **devenv** doesn't think `/build` is a file in the current folder. When it gets the command line, `/build` is interpreted as a command-line switch. However, Git Bash passes a command line to devenv, and if it doesn't pass `/build` then devenv can't guess what happened.

The root problem is that Git Bash tries to be useful, and converts `/build` into `\build`, indeed thinking that it was a file path. To avoid this, use `//build`.